# Jquery ui widgets out of position, but want to solve at least autocomplete

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, positioning, jquery-autocomplete

Is there any reason why widgets from jquery are sometimes out of position?

Dialog for example, it works well on my index page, but in nested pages it always appear [0,0] and now autocomplete is having the same problem, i have tried with:  appendTo: ".main"  option to see if it works, but the resulting menu is not being added.

I am using the plug-in inside a UserControl, so it is very important good position respect to the controls where is used.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the code or the page so we can see what's wrong with it...

Comment: Maybe your own webpage style is collinding with JQueryUI style. Make sure of this is not happening.